# Is it possible to sort an arraylist/hashset without the use of a comparator interface?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Basically would like to store an object of type Stations (string rerpesentation of the Station name) into alphabetical order from an array. But I can't modify the stations class to make it comparable as it has been predefined for me. Are there any other methods of sorting an array list of type stations into alphabetical order, without implementing the comparator interface or using collections.sort()

Comment: Why is there a restriction to create a Comparator<Station> (not making Station implements Comparable, but definining a Comparator to provide a criteria for sorting two Stations)?

Comment: You could use the cumbersome approach of manually iterating / checking each value and sorting the list. But the question is why don't you want to use Comparator?

Comment: You don't need to extend or touch the Station class to create a Comparator for it

Comment: @Claudio - He doesn't want to use Collections.sort as well. So, what good would a comparator be ?

Comment: @TheLostMind you can create a new TreeSet with that comparator and addAll the elements. I don't know. I just trying to figure out why the restrictions.

Comment: Why can't you use the `Comparator` interface? Is it homework? If it is, then you should say so and implement the sorting algorithm yourself. But in all other cases the `Comparator` interface is really great.

Comment: I assume the OP is mistaken and actually can use both `Comparator` and  `Collections.sort`, but wasn't aware that it's possible to do so without modifying the original class to make it `implement Comparable`.

Comment: ahhhh yes, Alnitak is correct

Comment: @Alnitak - Exactly. Otherwise like Roland Illig says, he will have to write his entire sorting logic himself.

Comment: @TheLostMind at which point Artur's (now deleted) answer is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user3603183 if you can still see it on-screen, there's a deleted answer that tells you

Comment: @Alnitak - yes. Thats why I didn't downVote his answer. I merely pointed out what the OP thought he wanted. :(

Comment: @ArturMalinowski please undelete your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the original question was based on a misunderstanding, here is the solution, which *does* use the `Comparator` interface and `Collections.sort`, but it does not modify the original `Station` class. First, we have the class `Station` that we cannot modify.

```
public final class Station {
  private final String name;
  public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

In our own code we can define a new class:

```
public class StationByNameComparator implements Comparator<Station> {
  @Override
  public int compare(Station left, Station right) {
    String leftName = left.getName();
    String rightName = right.getName();
    return leftName.compareTo(rightName);
  }
}
```

The class `Station` can be left as is. Now we can use `Collections.sort` to sort the stations:

```
List<Station> stations = /* ... */;
Collections.sort(stations, new StationByNameComparator());
```

Comment: I cannot modify the station class to implement the comparable or comparator interface...

Comment: You don't need to modify the `Station` class. A `Comparator` is usually implemented in a completely different class, which in your case should be called `StationByNameComparator`.

Comment: Ahh I finally understand that, I was going through the examples online and they are so confusing!

Answer (score 1):

As a place-holder until Artur's answer is undeleted:

You can implement `Comparator` out of the class:

```
Collections.sort(listOfStations, new Comparator<Stations>() {
    public int compare(Stations s1, Stations s2){
      // logic here
    }
});
```

Comment: It says I can't instantiate the type Comparator<Stations>

Comment: @user3603183 did you import `java.util.Comparator` ?

Comment: Is your class perhaps called `Station` rather than `Stations` ?